# Test equality of sets in Erlang

Tags: functional-programming, erlang, set

Given a data structure for sets, testing two sets for equality seems to be a desirable task, and indeed many implementations allow this (e.g. builtin  sets in python).

There are different set implements in Erlang: `sets`, `ordsets`, `gb_sets`. Their documentation does not indicate, whether it is possible to test equality using term comparison ("=="), nor do they provide explicit functions for testing equality.

Some naive cases seem to allow equality testing with "==", but I have a larger application where I'm able to produce `sets` and `gb_sets` which are equal (tested with the function below) but do not compare equal with "==". For `ordsets`, they always compare equal. Unfortunately I haven't found a way to produce a minimal example for cases where equal sets do not compare equal with "==".

For reliably testing equality I use the following function, based on this [theorem on set equality](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_Definitions_of_Set_Equality):

```
%% @doc Compare two sets for equality.
-spec sets_equal(sets:set(), sets:set()) -> boolean().
sets_equal(Set1, Set2) ->
    sets:is_subset(Set1, Set2) andalso sets:is_subset(Set2, Set1).
```

My questions:

1. Is their a rationale, why Erlang set implementations do not offer  explicit equality testing?
2. How to explain the difference when testing set equality with "==" with for the different set implementations?
3. How can produce a minimal example of `sets` where "==" does not compare equal but the sets are equal given the above code?

**Some thoughts on question 2:**

The documentation for `sets` states, that "The representation of a set is not defined." where as the documentation of `ordsets` states, that "An ordset is a representation of a set". The documentation on `gb_sets` does not give any comparable indication.
The following comment, from the [source code of the `sets` implementation](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/lib/stdlib/src/sets.erl), seems to reiterate the statement from the documentation :

> Note that as the order of the keys is undefined we may freely reorder keys within in a bucket.

My interpretation is, that term comparison with "==" in Erlang works on the representation of the sets, i.e. two sets only compare equal if their representation is identical. This would explain the different behavior of the different set implementations but also reinforces the question, why there is no explicit equality comparison.

Comment: I think there's no particular reason why there's no explicit equality test. If you submit a pull request implementing such a function in all three sets implementations, it would probably be accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ordsets` are implemented as a sorted list, and the implementation is fairly open and meant to be visible. They are going to compare equal (`==`), although `==` means that 1.0 is equal to 1. They won't compare as strictly equal (`=:=`).

`sets` are implemented as a form of hash table, and its internal representation does not lend itself to any form of direct comparison; as hash collisions happen, the last element added is prepended to the list for the given hash entry. This prepend operation is sensitive to the order in which the elements are added.

`gb_sets` are implemented as a general balancing tree, and the structure of a tree does depend on the order in which the elements were inserted and when rebalancing took place. They are not safe to compare directly.

To compare two sets of the same type together, an easy way is to call `Mod:is_subset(A,B) andalso Mod:is_subset(B,A)` -- two sets can only be subsets of each other when they're equal.

Comment: There is a error in the last sentence: Instead of "two sets can be subsets of each other when they're equal" it should be "two sets can not be subsets of each other when they're equal"

Comment: No, it is "can". `sets:is_subset(A, A)` is always true because every set is a subset of itself.

Comment: You're right of course. Thanks for the edit though, i think the new formulation is much clearer!